# Overloading C++ arithmetic operators

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to create some overloaded arithmetic operators which use inherited classes like this:

```
class Block {
    public:
        Block() {}
        virtual double Value() {};
};

class Constant : public Block {
    public:     
        Constant(double v) { value = v; }
        virtual double Value() { return value; }
    private:
        double value;       
};

class Add : public Block {
    public:
        Add(Block &a, Block &b) { value1 = &a; value2 = &b; }
        virtual double Value() { return value1->Value() + value2->Value(); }
    private:
        Block *value1;
        Block *value2;          
};

Block operator + (Block &a, Block &b) {
    return new Add(a, b);
}

int main() {
    Constant a(5.0);
    Constant b(6.0);
    printf("%.3f", (a+b).Value());
}
```

But I get following: `error: conversion from 'Add*' to non-scalar type 'Block' requested`

This is my first experience with OOP in C++ so is my idea even possible?

Comment: http://ideone.com/4nyxtE here is my final working edit.Though I know the code isn't the best one..

Comment: Well, now I can see my problem: x=a+b y=x This would work until I change a value of x. But I need to change y value on x change as well... :/

So the accepted answer helps to solve my question, however it doesn't solve my real problem..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule, operator overloading and inheritance don't
work well together, since in C++, operators generally have value
semantics.  There is one major exception, however, and if all of
the instances of your `Add` class are in fact the return value
of your `operator+` (temporaries), then you've effectively 
implemented compile time expression evaluation—a very
important optimization technique.  (In modern C++, this is
usually done using templates, rather than inheritance, but the
principle is the same.)

Because operators have value semantics, they should return
values, not pointers.  This means no `new`.  Another reason not
to use `new` is that anything that is `new`ed must be explicitly
deleted, and in most cases, there's no way to explicitly delete
a pointer returned as part of an expression.  And such a pointer
must be dereferenced as well.

EDIT:

I seem to have forgotten an important point: the declared return value of the operator *must* be the actual type you are returning, since your return expression will be copied into this type.  Thus:

```
Add
operator+( Block const& lhs, Block const& rhs )
{
    return Add( lhs, rhs );
}
```

Note too the `const`.  Without it, you cannot use the operator
on temporaries; e.g. `a + b + c` would be illegal (supposing
`a`, `b` and `c` are of type `Block`, or of some type derived
from it).

Comment: Thank you. But I suppose that I should edit my class definitons as well as it still doesn't work with your change.

Comment: Even with your addition of `const`, `a + b + c` will still be illegal because `Add` stores pointers to the objects it gets passed in the constructor, hence it will point to bygone values.

Comment: @KonradRudolph All instances of `Add` should be temporaries, whose lifetime lasts until the end of the full expression.  This is a more or less standard idiom, and works perfectly well.  (It's used in a lot of libraries, although the more modern libraries use templates, rather than inheritance.)

Comment: @milano Given that there is no dynamic allocation, there is no risk of anything not being freed.  Konrad was worried about accessing temporaries: if you write something like `Add x = a + b + c;`, this is a real issue.  Derived types like `Add` should _only_ occur as temporaries (as return values of `operator+`).  Assignment and copy should take a reference to the base class, and evaluate the expression immediately, in order to save the values.

Comment: @James Ah, true. I had thought that the usage would be along the lines of `auto result = a + b + c;`. In that case, evaluating `result` would be UB (in fact, I still think that this is the usage OP has in mind).

Comment: @JamesKanze
Well, now I can see my problem:
`x=a+b
y=x`

This would work until I change a value of x. But I need to change y value on x change as well... :/

Answer (score 4):

Since you did not mention the specific part of your code that causes the error, let me point it out:

```
Block operator + (Block &a, Block &b) {
    return new Add(a, b);
}
```

What exactly is going on here? Well, you are promising to return a `Block`, but you are actually returning `new Add(a, b)`, which is an `Add*`. And that is what the compiler is complaining about.

> This is my first experience with OOP in C++

One can tell from all the pointers and news and virtuals. Your code has serious lifetime issues.

I highly recommend you forget your C++ OOP knowledge and read [a good introductory book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).

Comment: I agree. Could you give me a little hint how to structure my classes in this case? I definitely plan to read more about OOP, not only in C++ but globally for all languages.

Comment: This won't work.  Return copies into the return type, here `Block`.  Which means slicing, and in the expression `(a+b).Value()`, it is `Block::Value()` which will be called.  (And how did such an obviously incorrect answer get so many up votes?)